# algorithm that finds the number of the shortest paths from given node s to any other node v?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

i want to find an algorithm that when given a graph G=(V,E) and a node s from V , for any node v in V it finds the number of the shortest paths from s to v .
i learned that BFS algorithm finds the shortest path from s to v , i just can't figure out how to use it in order to solve this problem .
any help would be very appreciated .

Comment: There's a pseudocode section on the Wiki page for BFS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: i don't want to change the code i just want to use the same BFS but in a smart way to solve ths problem as i heard thats the best way

Comment: Simply do not stp the search when you get to v. When you get to v record the path and continue the search,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudo-code (meaning untested Python) for this.

```
path_count[s] = 1
length_to[s] = 0
todo = [s] # A queue
while len(todo):
    v = todo.pop(0)
    for w in edges(graph, v):
        if w not in length_to:
            length_to[w] = length_to[v] + 1
            path_count[w] = 0
            todo.append(w)

        if length_to[w] == length_to[v] + 1:
            path_count[w] += path_count[v]
```

After this `length_to[v]` gives the length of the shortest path to `v` and `paths_to[v]` gives the number of shortest paths to `v`.  (Which is what you were looking for.)